# BeautifulSoup Webscraping Empty Result

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to retrieve information on ETF using IShares Website. However, when I try to call the `soup.find` function on a table, I get a `None` type object.

I tried to use the web inspector to find the element but I am stuck. For Example, I need to extract each ticker, name, and sector in the following table:

https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/products/etf-product-list?switchLocale=y&siteEntryPassthrough=true#!type=emeaIshares&tab=overview&view=list

I would appreciate any help/suggestion you have. I am new to this community and I just started using BeautifulSoup and this is my first webscraping project.

Thanks

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

website_url = requests.get('https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/products/etf-product-list#!type=emeaIshares&tab=overview&view=list').text
My_table = soup.find('td',{'class':' colLocalExchangeTicker mobile-on'})

My_table == None
```

> Out[13]: True

If the function was working fine, I would have expected to get a list of attributes (href, i.e the tickers) but it seems to be empty in this case.

Comment: What kind of information do you want to get?

Comment: Hello - thanks for your help. I am looking to extract all the information displayed in the table and store them into a dictionary. For simplicity let’s just assume I need the “Ticker” and “AUM”. Then I can replicate the process for the other contents of the table. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can get json with all that info by using url page does for content

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/products/etf-product-list/1524727817681.ajax?fileType=json')
s = json.loads(r.text.strip('\ufeff'))
print(s)
```

Comment: Hello QHarr -

1) How did you get the link to download the json?

2) Can you make an example how to use that JSON file to extrapolate all the list of "tickers" and "AUM" please? I am looking at the structure of the json file but it's not very cleaned and handy to me.

Thank you

Comment: From the network tab. And yes it is not friendly for working out where values are. I will see what I can do with it tomorrow.